# set width of embedded url

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

In R, the function `include_url()` from the knitr package allows to set the height, but not the width of an embedded iframe.

```
knitr::include_url("https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0", height="315")
```

The above will embedd the youtube with height =315 and width=672. Is there a way to set the width myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the chunk option `out.width`, e.g., `out.width="100%"`.